# org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop Exception

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, netbeans

I want to my NetBeans application add authentication with "Spring Security".

If I add to web.xml next code:

```
<listener> 
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class> 
</listener>
```

I get error:

```
NetBeans: Deploying on Apache Tomcat 8.0.27.0 
profile mode: false 
debug mode: false 
force redeploy: true 
Отмена развертывания... 
OK - Undeployed application at context path /task2Maven 
Развертывание на месте на C:\Users\Надюха\Documents\NetBeansProjects\task2Maven\target\task2Maven-1.0-SNAPSHOT 
deploy?config=file%3A%2FC%3A%2FUsers%2FD0F3%7E1%2FAppData%2FLocal%2FTemp%2Fcontext4982050153937982104.xml&path=/task2Maven 
FAIL - Deployed application at context path /task2Maven but context failed to start
```

logs Tomcat:

```
 18-Apr-2016 15:29:01.028 SEVERE [http-nio-8084-exec-151] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener 
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory 
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextCleanupListener.<clinit>(ContextCleanupListener.java:43) 
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:144) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4785) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5404) 
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232) 
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160) 
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1293) 
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:366) 
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) 
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) 
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) 
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) 
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) 
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:614) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142) 
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) 
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) 
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518) 
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091) 
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673) 
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500) 
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) 
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory 
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333) 
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167) 
    ... 37 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss this message:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory .
```

You miss the `commons-logging.jar` in the classspath

Comment: thanks. but now i have other error, log tomcat server org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext

Comment: @DmitriiKurylev, did you manage to resolve the issue? I'm getting a similar message and have not been able to make any meaningful headway. Any pointers are most welcome.